# vbscript to download a file (bypassing invalid certificate errors)

Tags: windows, ssl, vbscript, https, download

```
dim xHttp: Set xHttp = createobject("microsoft.xmlhttp")
dim bStrm: Set bStrm = createobject("Adodb.Stream")
xHttp.Open "GET", "https://www.website.com/apps/CertMgr.Exe", False
xHttp.Send

with bStrm
    .type = 1 '//binary
    .open
    .write xHttp.responseBody
    .savetofile "c:\CertMgr.Exe", 2 '//overwrite
end with
```

Using the above code I'm trying to download a file from a secure site to install a security certificate automatically, it works fine from a http site, but I'm needing to bypass the security errors. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You need to switch from MSXML2.XMLHTTP to [MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms766431%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and use the [setOption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763811%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method with the value [SXH_SERVER_CERT_IGNORE_ALL_SERVER_ERRORS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753798%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Just place the call between Open and Send.  Here's your example updated with the new code.

```
const SXH_SERVER_CERT_IGNORE_ALL_SERVER_ERRORS = 13056
dim xHttp: Set xHttp = createobject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
dim bStrm: Set bStrm = createobject("Adodb.Stream")
xHttp.Open "GET", "https://www.website.com/apps/CertMgr.Exe", False
xHttp.setOption 2, SXH_SERVER_CERT_IGNORE_ALL_SERVER_ERRORS
xHttp.Send

with bStrm
    .type = 1 '//binary
    .open
    .write xHttp.responseBody
    .savetofile "c:\CertMgr.Exe", 2 '//overwrite
end with
```

Comment: Not working: `download.vbs(2, 12) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: ActiveX component can't create object: 'microsoft.serverxmlhttp'`

Comment: Sorry for the typo. It should have been "MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP"