# How to translate wget command with custom header to vbscript or javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, vbscript, hta

For my html application I need to download JDK directly. This wget command seems to work for it

```
wget --no-cookies --header "Cookie: gpw_e24=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com" "http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7/jdk-7-linux-x64.tar.gz"
```

How can I translate this wget which is sending a custom header to ideally a vbscript line ( I prefer vbscript but will settle for javascript if i have to). P.S. I think the--no-cookies is optional but not sure. The reason I can't use a direct download link is that oracle requires users to click Accept Agreement on the download page below.

This link is for the latest download HTML page

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html

and this is the latest direct .exe link ( once you have clicked ACCEPT AGREEMENT)
http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u17-b02/jdk-7u17-windows-x64.exe

Or any other way to bypass the Accept Agreement problem?

This is my vbscript code which **gives an "unspecified error"**on line 4 with the `setRequestHeader`. the value ine gpw_e24 I tried the value i gave above too, didnt work.

```
Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
URL="http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u17-b02/jdk-7u17-windows-x64.exe"
saveto="c:\java.exe"     
objXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Cookie", "gpw_e24=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com"
objXMLHTTP.open "POST", URL, false
objXMLHTTP.send()

If objXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then
Set objADOStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
objADOStream.Open
objADOStream.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary

objADOStream.Write objXMLHTTP.ResponseBody
objADOStream.Position = 0 'Set the stream position to the start

Set objFSO = Createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If objFSO.Fileexists(saveTo) Then objFSO.DeleteFile saveTo
Set objFSO = Nothing

objADOStream.SaveToFile saveTo
objADOStream.Close
Set objADOStream = Nothing
End if

Set objXMLHTTP = Nothing

' Done
WScript.Quit
```

Comment: Why don't you just host the jdk yourself?

Comment: @Jack thats my backup plan if all else fails :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To download the file you should add the **request header** with name **Cookie** and value **gpw_e24=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com**

using code from [vbscript to download a file (bypassing invalid certificate errors)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096787/vbscript-to-download-a-file-bypassing-invalid-certificate-errors) you should try adding

```
xHttp.setRequestHeader "Cookie", "gpw_e24=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com"
```

Alternatively you can take **wget.exe** with your script and call it

Download binaries package from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm (you will need only **wget.exe**, there can be some required dll-s)

upd: Probably **wget.exe** from this binaries http://community.openscg.com/se/oscg_nixutils.jsp would be a better choice (because of no dependencies)

upd: I tried this, but oracle.com returns 403. **Your WGET command also does not work**.

```
Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
URL="http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u17-b02/jdk-7u17-windows-x64.exe"
saveto="c:\\Users\\Sanya_Zol\\INET_ALL\\2013\\_tmp\\20130326\\java-dl.exe"     
objXMLHTTP.open "POST", URL, false
objXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Cookie", "gpw_e24=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com%2Ftechnetwork%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2Fdownloads%2Fjdk7-downloads-1880260.html"
objXMLHTTP.send()

If objXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then
    Set objADOStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    objADOStream.Open
    objADOStream.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary

    objADOStream.Write objXMLHTTP.ResponseBody
    objADOStream.Position = 0 'Set the stream position to the start

    Set objFSO = Createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If objFSO.Fileexists(saveTo) Then objFSO.DeleteFile saveTo
    Set objFSO = Nothing

    objADOStream.SaveToFile saveTo
    objADOStream.Close
    Set objADOStream = Nothing
    Set objXMLHTTP = Nothing
Else
    MsgBox objXMLHTTP.Status
End if
```

Comment: that sounds very promising.trying it now

Comment: getting unspecified error :( I am updating the question to paste my vbscript code now

Comment: objXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader should be called **after** objXMLHTTP.open