# Error with vbscript to download a file bypassing invalid certificate errors

Tags: vbscript

having a similar problem to this post:

[Previous older post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096787/vbscript-to-download-a-file-bypassing-invalid-certificate-errors)

I'm trying to download a file from a webserver that works great on my internal and external network but not when i try to download from a secure https:// server.

I get the following error [Error picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQhwV.png)

I Have tried copying info from above problem but i'm not getting it right. can you please assist?

It works great internally and externally if not trying to access https!

```
Dim strURL, strFile, strFolder, oFSO, dt, oHTTP, oStream

strURL = "https://xx.xx.xx.xx/DataLogs/xxx.csv" 'external secure site
'strURL = "http://192.168.1.10/DataLogs/PLCData.csv" 'internal test
FileName="xxx.csv"
'FileName="PLCData.csv"
strFile = "xxx.csv" ''# The file name
'strFile = "PLCData.csv" ''# The file name
strFolder = "C:\PLC Data" '# The folder where to save the files

Const adTypeBinary = 1
Const adSaveCreateOverWrite = 2

''# If the download folder doesn't exist, create it
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If Not oFSO.FolderExists(strFolder) Then
 oFSO.CreateFolder strFolder
End If


Set dt = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemDateTime")
dt.SetVarDate Now
strFile = oFSO.GetBaseName(strFile) & "-" & Split(dt.Value, ".")(0) & "." & oFSO.GetExtensionName(strFile)

''# Download the URL 
Set oHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP") 'replace with? Set oHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP") MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP
oHTTP.open "GET", strURL, False
oHTTP.send

If oHTTP.Status <> 200 Then
 ''# Failed to download the file
 WScript.Echo "Error " & oHTTP.Status & ": " & oHTTP.StatusText
Else 
 Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
 oStream.Type = adTypeBinary
 oStream.Open

 ''# Write the downloaded byte stream to the target file
 oStream.Write oHTTP.ResponseBody
 oStream.SaveToFile oFSO.BuildPath(strFolder, strFile), adSaveCreateOverWrite
 oStream.Close
End If
```

Comment: Has this been posted?

Comment: It seems that your _secure https server_ is more likely to be an insecure https server... Did you try to open the URI in your webbrowser and look for messages similiar to that? (e.g. "untrusted connection")

Comment: Wait. If I open the address in firefox it says the connection is insecure. There is only a PLC home page when I tell Firefox to ignore that failure. In fact, something with your certificate is wrong or it certificates another hostname than your IP _"The certificate is only vaild for 192.168.1.10."_

Comment: Will this help?   https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/20980045/The-host-name-in-the-certificate-is-invalid-or-does-not-match.html   "server.address.com" may has invalid certificate or certificate from unknown issuer. You can ignore it and use the special option 
xmlhttp.setOption(2, xmlhttp.getOption(2) - 13056)

Comment: Any other Thoughts Clijsters?