# VB script has error "Security certificate required to access this resource is invalid" from msxml3.dll, and option 13056 not working

Tags: vba, windows, vbscript, xmlhttprequest, msxml3

I am having this issue now, with code:

```
set xmlhttp=CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
xmlhttp.Open "Get" url, false, proxyUser, proxyPass
xmlhttp.send
```

Then I am having this error:
"Security certificate required to access this resource is invalid" from msxml3.dll

I searched a bit and found that using option 13056 might help,
so I added this:

```
xmlhttp.setOption(2)=13056
```

But was reminded that "Object doesn't support this property or method: 'xmlhttp.SetOption'".
I also tried:

```
xmlhttp.setOption 2, 13056
```

The outcome is the same. I also checked the object xmlhttp, which is not empty/NULL.

So what should be the fix?

Comment: I also tried using Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP instead of Microsoft.XMLHTTP, but it would timeout at the "send" stage.

Comment: Have you tried `WinHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1`?

Comment: Just tried, operation timeout.

Comment: Can you share the URL? I'd like to repro.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is proprietary and needs password.

Comment: Did you see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6840812/15764378)?

Comment: Yes, not working yet. I will play with it. Thank you!